# Clear Clipboard on SGS2 (api 10)

Tags: android, clipboard

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S2 and tried the following:

```
import android.text.ClipboardManager;
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipboard.setText(null);
```

and

```
clipboard.setText("");
```

It didn't work. Ideas?

Comment: Did it crash? Exception log? Did it just not work? Have you tried anything else?

Comment: No crash - just didn't clear the clipboard. TouchWiz seems to have implemented their own multi-item clipboard and hence ignores all the api calls to Clipboard Manager. It crashes with NoClassDef or something like that (I uninstalled TouchWiz now) when I tried to use setPrimaryClip because its not in api 10. I was just hoping there was some easy way around or some comfirmation that TouchWiz is indeed ignoring this clipboard API.

Answer (score 4):

Their is a bug with the Samsung Galaxy. It doesn't accept setting the clipboard to a blank value. You could try setting it to a space instead.

```
clipboard.setText(" ");
```

For further information check [this](http://code.google.com/p/keepassdroid/issues/detail?id=204)

Comment: I'll get hold of my friend's stock SGS2 and test... mine has CyanogenMod on it atm...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried .setPrimaryClip(ClipData clip)? The documentation reads:

> public void setPrimaryClip (ClipData clip)
>
> Since: API Level 11 Sets the current primary clip on the clipboard.
>   This is the clip that is involved in normal cut and paste operations.
>   Parameters
>
> clip  The clipped data item to set.

According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), setText() is deprecated.

I know this question is old, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Yeah - that method is only from API 11. SGS2 is running 2.3 so it's not available.

Answer (score 0):

clear clip bord for v3.0 api-11

clipboard1 = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

```
    clipboard1
            .addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {

                public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                    copyText = (String) clipboard1.getText();
                    Log.d("Copytext", copyText);
                    Toast.makeText(javaButtonTest.this, copyText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    if (clipboard1.hasText()) {
                        copyText = (String) clipboard1.getText();
                        clipboard1.setText("");
                    }

                }
            });
```