# Clipboard is not getting clear

Tags: android, clipboard, clipboarddata, clipboardmanager

I have created a android application where i am clearing clipboard in application's onPause method
using this code

```
ClipboardManager clipboard =  (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            appClipData = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("", ""));
```

This code is working on almost all device but its not working on samsung s4
My samsung s4 have android 4.4.2 os

Please help me.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Above code doesn't work for SGS 5 and Samsung Galaxy Note 3/4 - while for other it does work

Comment: same issue on samsung s4 and s5

Comment: see [anser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362244/clear-clipboard-on-sgs2-api-10)here.Their is a bug with the Samsung Galaxy